# Where to find lists of nouns broken down by category?

Tags: words

Can anyone point me in the direction of a website with lists e.g. of countries, colours, animals etc which can be used when creating arrays. I have seen a few country lists in arrays but is there a site which has loads? It would save me, and probably quite a few other people, a lot of typing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Arrays and lists are *containers* for data. This question is asking "Where can I get the *data*?" But, unfortunately, this question doesn't even limit to a specific *kind* of data. (There are numerous [closed] questions that ask about specific kinds of data: e.g. countries).

Comment: I am aware that arrays are containers for data but I have seen some sites offering pre-written array declarations. Clearly this depends on the language being used but I just wanted to know if anyone knew of any sites which had a collection already where you could maybe choose the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to simply take each item, one at a time, and google it. Wikipedia is a good source for lists, then you can quickly assemble them into whatever format you like.

For example, if you google 'list of sovereign states', you'll get the country list from Wikipedia. Copy and paste it, then with an excel grid or a little macro action, you can spruce it up to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

About countries list , use this site: **[ip2nation.com](http://ip2nation.com)**

It has database of countries list with IP addresses.